# ASCII + Numeric Keypad

Tags: ascii, non-ascii-characters

I believe I have a standard Win7 Pro setup. I know that when I hold down the alt key and type some digits I can get the extended Ascii character set, up to 255. But I've also noticed that when I type alt+larger numbers I get different code pages. In this text box I can type alt+ plus sign and then 0254 and I get what seems to be this Cryllic letter  þ And alt plus +sign+ 0232 gets this: è (e with accent aigu) and so forth. Is there a list of how these alt + plus sign + 3 digits maps to what letter?

Looking at these characters in Notepad++ I see that they are generated by 0xC3 0xBE and 0xC3 and 0xA8. BUT if I type alt+195 (which is 0xC3 in Decimal) followed by 190 (0xBE) I get two different charcters (mapped to 190 and 195). How does the app know to combine the two? There is nothing in the raw data to show that?